# how to delete cell value if cell is containing special text

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete the value of a cell with vba, if the cell contains the phrase "01.01.1970 01:00:00"
The cell should be empty afterwards.
This date is only in column C and can exist in many rows.
The sheet has a lot of rows with different dates.
I only found ways, how to delete an entire row or column, if a cell contains a specific phrase, but I only want to delete the cell value.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Then just use `cells(row, col) = ""`

Comment: Look at the [Range.Replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx).

Comment: I don't get it, i tried it now with may different codes, but with everyone nothing happens.
Could there be a problem, that the date and the time isn't a text?
The cells are not as text formatted they were formatted as custom field (DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS)

Comment: I uploaded now my complete csv file with the macro, maybe there is a better and nicer solution, as to delete the cell value "01.01.1970  01:00:00".
If you will take a look at my vba code you can find that i have to convert a unix timecode to date and time, this is done with a formula. The formula will be copied to column D all the way down, even if in column C no unix timecode exist.
<br>
This is now the problem, so i thought i delete afterwards the date 01.01.1970, or maybe there is a better solution that the formula will only be copied if in column C in the same row a unix timecode exists.

Comment: here the [Dropbox Link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14554224/Macro_and_CSV.zip)  with my files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution / workaround with the following code

```
'START: CONVERT UNIX TIMECODE
    Range("D1").EntireColumn.Insert
    lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D2").Formula = "=(C2/86400)+25569+(+1/24)"
    Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
    Columns("D").NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS"
    Columns("D").Copy
    Columns("D").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Columns("C").Delete
    Range("C1").Value = "'Druckbeginn"
'END: CONVERT UNIX TIMECODE


'START: CHANGE FORMAT OF COLUMN D TO TEXT
    Columns("C").NumberFormat = "@"
'END: CHANGE FORMAT OF COLUMN D TO TEXT


'START: DELETE SPECIFIC TEXT, THE NUMBER 25569.* IS FOR THE DATE AND EACH TIME FROM 01.01.1970
    Columns("C").Replace "25569.*", "", xlPart
'END: DELETE SPECIFIC TEXT


'START: CHANGE FORMAT OF COLUMN D TO DATE AND TIME
    Columns("C").NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS"
'END: CHANGE FORMAT OF COLUMN D TO TEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Range.Replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx). You will want to localize the cells to be examined to column C.

```
with activesheet   '<-set this worksheet reference properly!
    .columns(3).replace what:="01.01.1970 01:00:00", _
                        replacement:=vbnullstring, lookat:=xlwhole
end with
```

Comment: i don't get this code working.
but i tried it with a workaround but this is also not working. i changed the format of the cells (which was a custom format DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS) to text. afterwards i got a number and for the date 01.01.1970 01:00:00 the number was always "25569,0416666667".
So I thought i will look for the text "25569,0416666667" and replace it, but this does also not work, but i don't know why.

Comment: This i my code:
        Range("D1").EntireColumn.Insert
        lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("D2").Formula = "=(C2/86400)+25569+(+1/24)"
        Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
        Columns("D").NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS"
        Columns("D").Copy
        Columns("D").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'Columns("C").Delete
        Range("D1").Value = "'Druckbeginn"

        Columns("D").NumberFormat = "@"

        Columns("D").Replace "25569,0416666667", "", xlPart

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Untested)

```
Dim RowCount as integer, i as integer

RowCount = Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 to RowCount
    If Range("C" & i).Value = "01.01.1970 01:00:00" Then
    Range("C" & i).ClearContents
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: this code is not working, because i get an compile error, an excel marks the following in blue

![here the screenshot](http://imageshack.com/a/img905/7226/olaQwO.jpg).